user.username shows incorrect information about the logged in user name
views.py
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Account has been updated')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)

users/profile.html
  <h1>{{ user.username }}</h1>
  <h2>{{ user.email }}</h2>
  <img src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" width="200" style="border: 3px solid black;">
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ u_form }}
    {{ p_form }}
    <button type="submit">Update profile</button>
  </form>

models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

forms.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']

When I submit a form that does not pass any validator, for example such a username already exists, then {{user.username}} is still changed to this incorrect username, but nothing changes in the database as the form does not pass validation and that's fine, but why does {{user.username}} become equal to this non-validated value?
I expected {{user.username }} to remain the same as in the database and as the logged in user's data

I am actually having an issue understanding your problem. When you submit the form and it gives you an invalid username because you have some type of unique constraint, that is accurate. It should show an error message

@ViaTech, Corrected the wording. No, that's not the point, it's good that it shows the error. The point is that {{user.username}} becomes equal to the value that was not validated, it shouldn't change {{user.username}}.

Hmm...can we see your settings and how you are defining your user model? Django passes an AnonymousUser in as the session if not authenticated

Maybe providing the forms would reveal an issue

I provided all necessary information

I think that when the form is submitted and you use instance=request.user you associate the form with the model instance, so in python it is changed even though it is not changed in the database until the form is actually saved.  What happens when the incorrect username shows up and you refresh the page?  I'm guessing that the correct username will now show.

@raphael, yes, but only if I click on profile link because you need GET method to do it. But I want to do POST request and if there is non valid data then just showing that errors but not changing {{ user.username }} until user send valid form.

Somehow, after calling u_form.is_valid() the request.user.username is being changed temporarily. The solution for now is to store the original username into a variable and use it to restore when form is invalid. Also, we need to update it with form data when its valid (redirect is reduntant, can be removed) :
@login_required
def profile(request):
    initial_username = request.user.username

    if request.method == "POST":
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            request.user.username = u_form.cleaned_data["username"]
            messages.success(request, f"Account has been updated")
        else:
            request.user.username = initial_username

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {"u_form": u_form, "p_form": p_form}
    return render(request, "users/profile.html", context)


But now I'm getting an error "UnidentifiedImageError at /profile/" on u_form.save()

Nervermind, what I am suggesting is totally wrong, because if you want to update an instance you need to pass it to the form anyways. Its changing request.user.username after we calll .is_valid, I still don't know why, yet.

For now, its a work around, I am still not sure why this happens exactly.

Basically Django updates the model instance and calls the instances methods to validate the object. This means even though the form is invalid Django is going to update the object passed to the form which in this case is request.user (Which is the same as the user object in the template).

@AbdulAzizBarkat thank you for the explanation. Indeed I created an instance of the object using request.user and happened exactly as you said. Although, we would still have to update request.user.username on form validity ^^.

@Niko updating request.user.username IMO isn't a great solution because if you update the template to render more attributes of the user, the invalid values from the form for those might still end up rendering. It is simpler to just either clone the user object or load them one more time from the database.

@AbdulAzizBarkat And I agree with you, but if request.user is being modified, then we would have to update it anyways, with either new object instance, no?

Problem
If the user submits the form the if request.method == 'POST' block kicks in, which binds the form to the data being sent (UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)).
Next the form is checked with if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid(): but it fails.  So what happens now?
My guess is that you think the else clause will kick in, but it doesn't because the indentation shows that it will only kick in if the original if (if request.method == 'POST') fails, which it does not becuase it was a POST request.
Therefore, u_form and p_form are still bound with their incorrect data, there is NO redirect, and the return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context), which renders the form with the incorrect data is what kicks in.
Solution
Put the unbound forms before the if request.method == 'POST'.
@login_required
def profile(request):

    u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
    p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Account has been updated')
            return redirect('profile')

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)


It is absolutely the same as my code, because with a GET request it will not go into the if statement, but if there is a POST request it will change the u_form and p_form variables.
